# Editable apex interactive report

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have created a simple interactive report in Apex, I would like to be able to edit the records in this interactive report. Did I need to specify this when creating it. All of the records have a pencil next to them when I click on this it does not enable me to edit them.

How do I go able this?

Answer (score 1):

You want to create a new page, and use the "Form on table With a Report" template.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the IR, then create a new blank form, add a form template to it based on  the same table as the IR.
Then create the form as you normally would with the create update etc.
Go back to the interactive Report select the attributes for the interactive report region and in the properties select Link Column and set that to link to custom target.
In the pop-up dialogue select the form you just created and remember to add the primary key from the interactive report matching primary key on the form you're going to.
Save your work run the IR and click the pencil and it will navigate to the form you just created and will show the correct record to be edited.

Normally if you think you're going to want an IR with a CRUD  form, then create both at the same time using the form on table with report as previous poster mentioned.
But once you have you the IR to report this is the easier option.